# How to turn on iPhone Retina in iOS Simulator?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, ios-simulator

I built and ran an iOS 4.3 app in Simulator. It initially brings up an iPhone 4 shell. Although all real iPhone 4s have retina display, this simulated iPhone 4 only has a resolution of 320x480.

[image: iphone simulator]

I look in `Hardware > Device`. There's a checkmark next to the normal iPhone. So I'm using an iPhone 4 case but displaying normal iPhone resolution? I'm already confused!

- iPad
- ✔ iPhone
- iPhone (Retina)

I then switch over to *iPhone (Retina)*. Strangely, it opens iPad with the same 320x480 resolution. Both the shell and the resolution are wrong here!

[image: ipad simulator]

How am I supposed to turn Retina on and off and show it in the right shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iOS Simulator does indeed scale. I have no real reason to present on why it would choose the iPad shell, but the purpose of the scaling is to make sure it fits on your screen and stays (relatively) close to handset sizes. Be sure to check `Window -> Scale` and set it to whatever you find appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

iPhone (Retina) is the correct device to be choosing, but I'm not sure why Apple decided to use the iPad shell for that one. To enter 640x960 mode, go to Window > Scale and set it to 100%.

Comment: Agreed, iPhone (Retina) displays your image at 640x960, regardless of the iPad shell. If you chose iPad you'd get your app in a 1024x768 area, which you could pixel-double with the 2x button. Ignore the shell and choose iPhone (Retina).